# Get BeautifulSoup Class attribute value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the value of only 3.5,4.3 and 2.5 from the below structural html content using BeautifulSoup. Please help how to scrap the value.

```
<div class="abc">3.5<img class="def" src=''</div>
<div class="abc">4.3<img class="def" src=''</div>
<div class="abc">2.5<img class="def" src=''</div>
```

Comment: Is there any code you have writtent to try and solve this problem? Would be helpful if you posted that as well.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all
--> Searching by CSS class
soup.find_all("div", class_="abc")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick snippet on how to achieve this. Since you didn't provide any code, I don't know where your html is coming from, so I'll just set your given html to a variable.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = """
<div class="abc">3.5<img class="def" src=''</div>
<div class="abc">4.3<img class="def" src=''</div>
<div class="abc">2.5<img class="def" src=''</div>
"""

# Initialize html parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Find all div elements with class 'abc'
div_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='abc')

# Extract the text from each div element and print the value
for div in div_elements:
    value = div.text.strip()  # Get the text and remove leading/trailing spaces
    print(value)
```

This will print out:

```
3.5
4.3
2.5
```